# Otelbayev's approach to Navier-Stokes

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics

[Recent news](http://bnews.kz/en/news/post/180213/) post that [Mukhtarbai Otelbayev](http://otelbaev.com/?p=1) from Eurasian National University has shown existence of strong solutions of the Navier-Stokes equation in the article

> ["Existence of a strong solution of the Navier-Stokes equations"](http://www.math.kz/images/journal/2013-4/Otelbaev_N-S_21_12_2013.pdf)

which shall already be published in a [Russian journal](http://www.math.kz/index.php/ru/513). It's also claimed that that paper solves the respective Clay Millenium Problem. Given that the paper is in Russian and I haven't heard about the author and the journal, I am curios if somebody can shed some light on the issue. Has Otelbayev found some genuinely new approach to Navier-Stokes?

**Remark 1:** There is already some discussion going on at several other places on the internet and I am aware that it has been discussed ([e.g. here](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1438/mochizuki-proof-of-abc)) if questions of this type are suitable here, but I thought that MO would generate most reliable answers quickly and would be a good place to keep relevant information.

**Remark 2:** User [myw01](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121064/myw01) from math.stackexchange has started [an english translation](https://github.com/myw/navier_stokes_translate) of the article on github. To me as a layman in Navier-Stokes it starts out reasonable…

**Remark 3:** As Sam Hopkins noted in a comment below, Terry Tao just published the preprint ["Finite time blowup for an averaged three-dimensional Navier-Stokes equation"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0290) which indicates that a positive solution of global existence of Navier-Stokes equations is "improbable" and also proposes a program for
adapting approach laid out in the paper to the true Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: «To me as a layman in Navier-Stokes it starts out...» is a rather bad way to start an evaluation of work in such a delicate subject!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Granted… But actually the english translation is not very far yet and ends before analysis starts. The introduction seems to be ok in that it cites relevant literature. I just added the respective remark to i) draw attention to the translation project and ii) to indicate that it is not obviously nonsense.

Comment: Relevant meta threads: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/927/what-is-our-policy-on-asking-about-correctness-of-preprints?rq=1 http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1263/can-i-ask-whether-or-not-a-paper-that-proves-p-np-is-correct The consensus seems to be that questions about the correctness of a specific paper are not desired here.

Comment: I strongly think that MO is not an appropriate place to vet solutions of famous open problems.  As far as this one goes, people claim such things all the time, and 99.999% of them fall apart.  It's not worth getting excited by yet another one.  And the fact that this rumor was spread by a press release makes it sound fishier still.

Comment: (I also wouldn't get excited by the fact that it is being published in some journal; there are plenty of obscure journals with low standard that publish such things all the time).

Comment: Well, it seems pretty hard to find the right words as a non-native… I added the reference to the journal as an additional piece of information and nothing more. I also see some red flags but but basically I hoped that somebody fluent in Russian and PDE/fluid dynamics would jump in and say something like "on page X there is this well known error" or "this step over there seems new"… But anyway, if the consensus is that questions like this are not appropriate, feel free to close.

Comment: @Dirk I put in the final vote to close since you graciously accepted closure, but thank you for pointing out the translation project, this will be helpful in getting more eyes onto the paper to check it (given Otelbayev's publication record, I'm not dismissing his attempt on face value, even if it's a long shot).

Comment: From the translation so far, I can't see how Otelbaev, with the additional assumptions he makes (zero initial velocity, only finite time interval), goes past what is listed as already known on the problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_existence_and_smoothness#Partial_results). But this isn't really the place to discuss this (and I'm also no expert in PDEs)

Comment: It's probably worth adding a reference to a recent post of Terence Tao that asserts that "abstract" solutions to the Navier-Stokes problem are bound to fail: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/finite-time-blowup-for-an-averaged-three-dimensional-navier-stokes-equation/